# Java library function to turn arbitrary String into XML ID

Tags: java, xml, escaping

I think this must exist somewhere, but it's very difficult to search.

Library can be JDK, Guava, Commons-lang, xml processing library or any reasonably well-known library.

The behavior can be stripping or escaping, but for a bunch of unique, human-readable names with no special characters, the escaping result should also be unique and reasonably human-readable.

Thanks.

Comment: ID is defined by http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#ID see also NCNAME http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#NCName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most probably do not want to *escape* the string (which is generally reversible), and instead want to "sanitize" the string (retain only a subset of its original characters, those that are safe, possibly making it impossible to recover the original string). As you mentioned in comments, IDs can be quite picky.

So we choose a safe range and remove anything outside of that. Additionally, if it starts with a non-letter, we prepend an 'i' to make it compliant.

```
public String toSafeId(String s) {
     s = s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", "-"); // replaces runs of non-valid by '-'
     return s.length() > 0 && Character.isLetter(s.charAt(0)) ? s : "i" + s;
}
```

Note that this does not enforce uniqueness. To enforce it, wrap it up with a Set:

```
public class XmlIdGenerator {
    private HashSet<String> used;

    // provides a unique ID
    public String generate(String s) {
        String base = toSafeId(s);
        String id = base;
        for (int i = 1; used.contains(id); i++) {
            id = base + "-" + i;
        }
        used.add(id);
        return id;
    }
}
```

Use as:

```
XmlIdGenerator gen = new XmlIdGenerator(); // build a new one for each document
String oneId = gen.generate("   hi there sally!");      // -> "hi-there-sally"
String anotherId = gen.generate(" hi there.. sally?");  // -> "hi-there-sally-1"
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am not sure this will be enough though. The `NCNAME` production quoted in Aubin's comment above is way narrower than what `escapeXml` escapes. For example, you cannot have digits at the beginning of an ID.

Comment: True - this only escapes the characters. However, you can easily guarantee that particular part by adding an "i" prefix.

Comment: Yes, but escaping symbols like `^` still doesn't make them valid in IDs. They will either have to be removed or escaped differently.

Comment: Changes my approach from "alter the string as little as possible" to "better safe than sorry"

Comment: I had to change `return Character.isLetter(s.get(0) ? s : "i" + s;` by `return Character.isLetter(s.charAt(0)) ? s : "i" + s;` because a parenthesis was missing and the method get on String was undefined.

Comment: I had to change `return Character.isLetter(s.get(0) ? s : "i" + s;` by `return Character.isLetter(s.charAt(0)) ? s : "i" + s;` because a parenthesis was missing and the method get on String was undefined.

Comment: @Leoz addressed. Also added fix for empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes i use the library XStream, check this "2 minute tuturial"

http://x-stream.github.io/tutorial.html

---

create the objects that have the info

```
public class Person {
  private String firstname;
  private String lastname;
  private PhoneNumber phone;
  private PhoneNumber fax;
  // ... constructors and methods
}

public class PhoneNumber {
  private int code;
  private String number;
  // ... constructors and methods
}
```

start the xtream

```
XStream xstream = new XStream();
```

insert the info as alias

```
xstream.alias("person", Person.class);
xstream.alias("phonenumber", PhoneNumber.class);
```

Insert info

```
Person joe = new Person("Joe", "Walnes");
joe.setPhone(new PhoneNumber(123, "1234-456"));
joe.setFax(new PhoneNumber(123, "9999-999"));
```

Generete the XML

```
String xml = xstream.toXML(joe);
```

Comment: Add the specific code snippet - just linking to the information is not considered a good answer.

Comment: Reverted the negative, but it does not do anything about IDs. The question is "how do I turn my string into an ID", not "how do I create an XML document programmatically"